# Find all natural number $n$ such that $n^2 + 2\mid 2001n + 2$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility

> Find all natural number $n$ such that $n^2 + 2\mid 2001n + 2$

My idea is to eliminate $n$ on the right side of divisibility sign so it becomes only an integer, without any variable.
$$\label{eq1}
n^2 + 2\mid 2001n + 2\tag{1}
$$

Here's my approach.
To eliminate $n$, we need another linear "right side". So we try to find something looks like $$n^2 + 2 \mid a(n^2 + 2) - b(2001n + 2)$$
where $a$ and $b$ are function of $n$. A suitable choice would be $a = 2001$ and $b = n$, which gives $$n^2 + 2 \mid 2001(n^2 + 2) - n(2001n + 2)$$
thus 
$$\label{eq2}
n^2 + 2 \mid 4002 - 2n\tag{2}
$$
Now we have two linear right sides, eliminating $n$ by multiplying \eqref{eq1} by $2$ and \eqref{eq2} by $2001$ gives us $$n^2 + 2\mid 2(2001n + 2) + 2001(4002 - 2n) = 4 + 2001\cdot 4002$$
or $n^2 + 2\mid 8008006$. We only need to find the divisor of $8008006$ for which when we subtract 2 from it will give a square number. But this is somewhat laborious. Is there any other way to solve this?

Edit: The solutions I got $n = 6,9,2001$

Thanks!

Comment: Labels and refs don't seem to work here, unfortunately. At least not for me. Maybe try `\tag` instead of `\label` and then write out the label by hand when referring back to it?

Comment: Any other way would be either equivalently complicated or worse.

Comment: `\ref` or `\eqref` needs both `\label` and `\tag` in MathJaX.

Answer (score -1):

Well, we know $2001n+2 \geq n^2+2$. Then $2001n-n^2 | n^2+2$ or $n^2+2|2001n-n^2$. Assume the first case is true. We divide this into two subcases: $n$ even and $n$ odd. If $n$ odd, then we have a clear contradiction as the right side is $2 \pmod n$ and the left side is divisible by $n$. Otherwise, unless $n=2$, clearly $n$ must have a prime divisor other than 2 that divides the left side but not the right. Unfortunately for $n=2$, the left side is orders of magnitude larger than the right side. For the second case, we have the same issues for $n \neq 2$, and plugging in $n=2$ unfortunately leads us to conclude there are no solutions.

EDIT: It appears I forgot the case where $2001n-n^2=0$. This yields the solution of $n=2001$. Oops.
There is also a huge gaping hole in the second case. My logic for the first case does NOT hold for the second case.

Comment: What about $n=0,6,9$?

Comment: I'm looking through my solution right now, there is an error somewhere. This is rather embarrassing...